# PicklingError when using foreachPartition in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to map a function (which updates records in a Dynamodb table if a certain condition is met) to a large dataframe in Pyspark. I'm aware that functions are pickled and sent to executors, but I've been reading countless examples where the workaround is to insert your map function into the global scope. Unfortunately this has not worked for me.

```
def update_dynamodb(rows, dynamodb_tb_name, s3_bucket_name, region):
    dynamodb_table = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name = region).Table(dynamodb_tb_name)
    s3_bucket = boto3.resource('s3', region_name = region).Bucket(s3_bucket_name)
    for row in rows:
         # code that modifies Dynamodb is here....

dynamodb_write_df = df.repartition(num_executors * 2)
dynamodb_write_df.rdd.foreachPartition(lambda x: update_dynamodb(x, dynamodb_tb_name, raw_s3_bucket, region))
```

This code produces the error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o81.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
```

on this line:

```
dynamodb_write_df.rdd.foreachPartition(lambda x: update_dynamodb(x, eviv_dynamodb_tb, raw_s3_bucket, region))
```